# CSS Opacity not working in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to make the `background-color` of a `tr` opaque with this CSS:

```
.faded{
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

Here is my test HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class="faded">
        <td><div>testtesttesttestt</div></td>
        <td><div>testtsttesttesttt</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Everything works fine in IE9,10 FF24 Chrome 31+, but not in IE11.  **Please keep in mind that I don't care about the content of the table rows, only the background opacity.**  Screenshots and Jsfiddle below.

IE10:
[image: IE10]

IE11:
[image: IE11]

http://jsfiddle.net/ZB3CN/6/

So, what's going on here?

**EDIT: I've submitted a bug report to Microsoft:** https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/868842/ie-11-setting-css-opacity-on-a-table-row-doesnt-affect-the-background-color-of-that-row

**EDIT 2:  This bug was confirmed by Microsoft**

**EDIT 3:  Microsoft has moved this bug to a new location:** 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/212446/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That appears to be yet another IE bug.. As a work-around, you could instead add the `opacity` via the background property with a `rgba()` color. Then simply add the opacity to the `td` element.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/WCBWC/) - results seem consistent across browsers.

```
.faded {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
    height: 100px;
}
td {
    opacity:0.4
}
```

Comment: This does work in IE11.  I'm generating the HTML from code behind, and it's so much easier to just set a class on the element rather than have multiple CSS classes for different colors.

Comment: @ToastyMallows Yea, that sounds like a pain. I'm sure you're already aware of it, but you could apply the `opacity` to the `table` element instead - that appears to work in IE.. http://jsfiddle.net/NSc32/

Comment: I need to be able to make some rows opaque, and some rows not opaque.  But thanks for the suggestion, that would be a good fix.

Comment: @ToastyMallows You could also do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NsdH6/).. alternatively, the problem is eliminated if you change the display of the `td` element.. though not ideal, [this works](http://jsfiddle.net/2hrnX/).

Comment: the first one might actually work, I'll look into it more tomorrow.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: This works but it makes the code so much more complex.  I've submitted a bug report to Microsoft: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/868842/ie-11-setting-css-opacity-on-a-table-row-doesnt-affect-the-background-color-of-that-row

Comment: I'm going to accept this as an answer because I ended up going with one of the workarounds (setting the background color on all table cells instead of a table row).

Comment: One thing to note is that opacity adds transparency to both the parent AND child elements, while the rgba approach only adds transparency for the parent element.

Answer (score 8):

If someone else has a problem, it helped me:

```
.foo {
  opacity: 0.4;
  position: relative; /* for IE */
}
```

[More info](https://makandracards.com/makandra/21779-css-opacity-is-not-inherited-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60061727/4137880)

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me.

```
background-color: rgba(18, 21, 23, 0.3);
```

the last parameter is alpha channel (the opacity of the colour) you can pass it from 0.0 to 1.0 to adjust your colour opacity.

Answer (score -1):

add this line to the head of your html, and the opacity will work fine

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: Could you explain why this would help with making the opacity work in IE11?

Comment: @John Odom It has something to do with how the browser renders the page.

Comment: @JSON it does NOT.

Comment: @viking_grll then your issue has something other to due with IE 11.  Not sure what to say but this is how you get ie to render the css correctly

Comment: @JSON in the end I put the opacity on a div instead of on a table and that worked.

Comment: @viking_gril  did you clear your cache?  You gotta clear you cache if it is in a css file