# html - CSS Opacity different than 1 or 0 not working in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, opacity

I'm facing an issue with the css property opacity, with Internet Explorer 11.
The code is very simple:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<style>
div{
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
#d1{
  opacity: 1;
}
#d2{
  opacity: 0.7;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='d1'>df</div>
<div id='d2'>trtret</div>
</body>
</html>
```

On IE11, the opacity setting doesn't work for the second div. All others browsers are fine. I'm using Apache server through local uWamp (so it's a localhost website, but same matter when put online).

I know there are others topics on the subject, but no help from them so far...

Using the developer tools, I discovered that the opacity is set to 0 by IE:
[Wrong opacity in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFHXX.png)

Comment: working fine in IE11 using windows

Comment: Work fine on my IE too, have you tried to add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick with background-color worked, but the meta tag didn't change anything.

Finally I got the "opacity" css working by deleting the IE cache (`tools --> internet options --> general --> delete...`).

Comment: Well, the answer most useful is mine, and I cannot mark it as accepted, I have to wait 2 days.

Comment: @morgul It isn't a thank you answer. It provides a useful answer. We just have to edit out that thank you part.

Answer (score 1):

On old Internet Explorer versions you needed to add this to get transparency :

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=70);
```

or this :

```
filter : alpha(opacity=70)
```

But on IE10+ you don't need it anymore, you can use `opacity: 0.7`.

Try to add this line between your `<head>` tags :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

This line forces IE11 to use the most recent rendering engine (in that case the Edge engine).

Answer (score 0):

CSS opacity property seems to work fine with IE11, adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration at the top of html document (before `<html>` open tag)

(I apologize answering this question a little bit late (over three year). I guess this can be useful for someone still fighting with IE11).

Note: Tested with IE version 11.1622.16299.0