# IE11 a:Hover intermittent opacity failure

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The following code works perfectly in FF & Chrome but in IE11 fails more often than not (but not all the time - waving the mouse over the anchor tags *sometimes* changes the opacity). It's the inconsistency that's annoying.

Neither using the class selector or simple a:hover in the css solves the problem.

My Question: Has anyone else come across this issue - and can anyone recreate it?

IE11 version 11.0.9600.18537
Update 11.0.38

Note: This is a work machine and McAfee site advisor is installed: I'm not ruling out this as the cause but can't disable or uninstal it.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.abtn {
    display:block;
    background-color:#0B4499;
    border-radius:30px;
    border: 0px;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:8px 60px 8px 15px;
    color:#fff;
    width:220px;
    margin: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
}

a:hover {
    opacity:0.6;
}
/*
a[class*="abtn"]:hover {
    opacity:0.6;
}
*/

</style>
</head>
<body>
<a class="abtn" href="http://www.google.co.uk">Some text</a>
<a class="abtn" href="http://www.google.co.uk">Some words</a>
<a class="abtn" href="http://www.google.co.uk">Other gubbins</a>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Start>Run>iexplore.exe -extoff . To test IE in no Addons mode. Ctrl+Shift+H to view the Favorites center with the History tab, so you can delete previous history of your site and google domains. Internet Options>General tab, Colors button..... customize colors used on links in web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Work fine adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60061727/4137880)