# Why is hover function only working on some computers?

Tags: html, css, hover, internet-explorer-11

I have a simple hover function that makes the image more transparent. I'm trying to use the site on IE 11. The weird thing is that on some computers, it works how it's supposed to. On others also running IE 11, it doesn't. I don't know if this is a code problem or maybe just a settings issue. Any ideas?

Here is my image code:

```
<img alt="Home" class="auto-style8" src="http://contoso/AzureTeam/Images/Home.png">
```

Here is my css:

```
.auto-style8 {

        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }
 .auto-style8:hover {
         opacity: 0.4
    }
```

There's nothing too fancy too it. I don't really understand what is wrong.

Comment: *"Some computers"* doesn't help us much. What is different about the computers that have the issue? Can you reproduce it yourself and if so, under what circumstances?

Comment: i think this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504400/css-opacity-not-working-in-ie11

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* In this case you may have enough code but your question still needs enough info to reproduce. What version of IE11 are these computers running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using css Cross-Browser prefix

like this for example:

```
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);

  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.5;
```

Comment: Even though they're all using IE 11, adding the filter: alpha(opacity=50); made it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all of the computers are on the same version of IE 11? I had a similar issue.

You could try to cover all your bases by doing this:

```
 .auto-style8:hover {
     -webkit-opacity: 0.4;
     -khtml-opacity: 0.4;
     -moz-opacity: 0.4;
     -ms-opacity: 0.4;
     -o-opacity:0.4;
     -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40)";
     filter: alpha(opacity=40);
 }
```

Check out: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Answer (score -1):

About CSS Browser support:
The Opacity property works from the following Browser's version.

**Opacity**:

- IE: 9
- Firefox: 2
- Chrome: 4
- Safari: 3.1
- Opera: 9

Maybe in some computers, the IE version is older than 9.

And you should always use vendor prefix:

- webkit- (Chrome, Safari, newer versions of Opera.)
- moz- (Firefox)
- o- (Old versions of Opera)
- ms- (Internet Explorer)

If you have access to the computers which your code is not working, you could also test deleting the cache of that computer.

Press F12 > Network > F5 > Right click > Clear browser cache

Answer (score -1):

In IE6 :hover is applied only to HTML a elements that have an href attribute.

In IE7 :hover on elements other than anchors is often slow to react. On large tables this can prove to be almost unusable. A fix is to add position relative (assuming the element is not positioned) to the element being hovered.

In Internet Explorer version 8, the manipulation of elements with negative z-index is buggy when used in conjunction with :hover