# How can I make a separate opacity for IE browser?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

With the help of below css and Jquery, I have set default opacity is 0 and it will be 1 when page scrolled means Sticky footer is visible after some page scrolled.

I had applied below css for my site-footer:

```
.site-footer{
    opacity:0;  /*I have made this opacity 0 by default and once page scrolled down, it will convert to opacity:1 through jquery written in custom javascript section*/
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

And also applied below jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop()>100)
        {
            $(".site-footer").css({"opacity":"1"});
        }
        else
        {
            $(".site-footer").css({"opacity":"0"});
        }
    });
});
```

This code is running perfectly in other browser except IE (I used IE11), Footer is not visible on IE browser. When I inspect it, it will only take opacity:0 which is default opacity I had applied in above CSS means the Jquery I had applied above is not working on IE browser.

Please Suggest.

Comment: A few questions: Why do you use opacity to hide the element instead of display: none? Why do want to get it work in IE 11? And last question: Did you already use google to find an answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504400/css-opacity-not-working-in-ie11

Comment: There is any way to set some css only for IE11 browser?